# modifying the Javassist proxy naming policy

Tags: java, proxy, javassist, cglib

When creating proxies in CGLib using Enhancer, you can call `.setNamingPolicy(NamingPolicy n)` to change proxy class naming strategy to something other than the CGLib default.  Is there any way to do something similar in Javassist when using the ProxyFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for [ProxyFactory](http://opensourcejavaphp.net/java/javassist/javassist/util/proxy/ProxyFactory.java.html) I would say that it's not possible out-of-the-box at least:

```
private static synchronized String makeProxyName(String classname) {
    return classname + "_$$_javassist_" + counter++;
}
```

Comment: so the method that calls static makeProxyName is
  private void allocateClassName()
    {
        classname = makeProxyName(basename);
    }
Perhaps I could proxy the ProxyFactory itself, to replace allocateClassName functionality with something that builds the class name according to the policy that I want.  I just tried to quickly cobble something together, but it didn't work.  What do you think?

Comment: It's open source. Implement this feature and propose a patch?

Comment: Might be that I'll do t myself @kevinwelker :)

Comment: I'm not racing you to it, so if you do it, feel free to post an update here :-)

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub, it looks like about 6 months ago they [added a public field in ProxyFactory](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/commit/3358dc269352383eb5e9c186d24ff4a292eeb637) of type UniqueName that you can replace to change the naming policy.  This wasn't available when the question was first asked.